# Mappend Type to Make Optional Properties in Each Discriminate Union Case Mandatory

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

given the following discriminate union type

```
type DU =
|{kind?: "A", A: true}
|{kind?: "B", B: true, value?: number}
```

how do I create a mapped type that make all optional properties mandatory such that

```
type DU_Mandatory = ToMandatory<DU>
//such that 
type DU_Mandatory = 
|{kind: "A", A: true}
|{kind: "B", B: true, value: number}
```

Comment: You can just use [the provided `Required` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and write `Required<DU>`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0xPam).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?